# How can I catch an id in static urls and redirect it to new urls in wordpress [301]

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect old urls structure to new one in wordpress with 301, here is one of my old urls

```
example.com/en/news/1/13005/post_title
```

I want to catch `13005` which is the post id and redirect url to new structured parameter base wordpress url :

```
example.com/?p=13005
```

For some reasons i might need to add a specific number to all old ids,
How can i implement these redirections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding following rules in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/news/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/post_title$ http://example.com/?p=$2 [R=301,L]
```

For dynamic `post_title` you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^en/news/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://example.com/?p=$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but there are some points that you missed in this rule, the 'post_title' is dynamic and i might need to add specific number to id

Comment: @MrYar Updated answer for dynamic post_title, can u explain more about specific number

Comment: Fantastic, of course, in this example regular expression return '13005' as id, i need to add some specific number such as '5' to this id, i want to have this url:
example.com/en/news/1/13005/post_title => example.com/?p=13010

Comment: @MrYar I dont think of any way of doing this, however an easy substitute would be to add the number in id on the page instead of in the url